# AWS SES - am I doing it right?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I have an EC2 instance with some WordPress and drupal sites on them. Both have contact forms of some kind that kick off emails. I went through the approval process to allow my EC2 to send emails. I found a plethora of tutorials on how to actually accomplish sending of the emails inside one of the aforementioned CMS systems and settled on SES.

What I understand is that for each site/domain I need an authorized SES SMTP configured. Does this sound correct? Basically, I have this...

```
somesite.com -> SES: email@somesite.com
another.com -> SES: email@anothersite.com
andagain.com -> SES: email@andagain.com
```

For each site I need to reach out to someone and say "hey you're going to receive an email from AWS SES asking for authorization to use your email address."

Something feels off but can't figure out what it is. Am I doing this correct or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do, is to authorise the domain / email address you’re sending from. There is no need to authorise every receipient.

Don’t forget to remove sandbox limitations.

Comment: I did remove the sandbox limitations already, forgot to mention that. So, I wasn't saying I need to authorize all recipients, but if each site is a different domain, then the corresponding email address needs to be registered?

Comment: Either full domain, or you're certain that only certain emails will be used to send from, authorise that email directly, its easier. Saying this, I nearly always authorise domain name.

Comment: Didn't know you could authorize just the domain. Interesting. I will look into that. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, if You use different domains, You will need another registration method. However if the different domains are subdomains of the parent domain the only thing that You will need to do is verify the parent domain and then You are free to go with sending emails from all Your subdomains.